# Python schedule module not executing multiprocessing program

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, schedule

I have got three python scripts, scheduler one, multithreading one and another one is for multiprocessing. I am trying to execute the multiprocessing script with the help of scheduler. When I use multithreading instead of multiprocessing the program works. I can't figure out what is the issue. Below are the scripts for both multithreading and multiprocessing. I am doing all this in Windows using Python3.6. I just replace multiprocessing.py with multithreading.py in the scheduler.py and program works.

scheduler.py

```
def job():
  try :
    exec(open('multiprocessing.py').read())
 except Exception as e:
    print(e)

schedule.every(100).seconds.do(job)


while True:  
   schedule.run_pending()
```

multiprocessing.py

```
for i in range(cores):
            start = i*singleLength
            processName = 'Process-'+str(i+1)
            if (len(linesList) / 2 == 0 ) and (i == cores - 1):
                end = singleLength + (i*singleLength)
                values = (linesList[start:end],processName)
            elif (len(linesList) / 2 != 0) and (i == cores - 1):
                #semiListLength = len(linesList[start:])
                values = (linesList[start:],processName)
            else:
                end = singleLength + (i*singleLength)
                #semiListLength = len(linesList[start:end])
                values = (linesList[start:end],processName)
            processList.append(multiprocessing.Process(target = FTMain.parsing, args = values))

        for i in range(cores):
            processList[i].start()

        for i in range(cores):
            processList[i].join()
```

multithreading.py

```
 for i in range(cores):
            start = i*singleLength
            processName = 'Thread-'+str(i+1)
            if (len(linesList) / 2 == 0 ) and (i == cores - 1):
                end = singleLength + (i*singleLength)
                #semiListLength = len(linesList[start:end])
                values = (linesList[start:end],processName)
            elif (len(linesList) / 2 != 0) and (i == cores - 1):
                #semiListLength = len(linesList[start:])
                values = (linesList[start:],processName)
            else:
                end = singleLength + (i*singleLength)
                #semiListLength = len(linesList[start:end])
                values = (linesList[start:end],processName)
            processList.append(threading.Thread(target = FTMainTemp.parsing, args = values))

        for i in range(cores):
            processList[i].start()

        for i in range(cores):
            processList[i].join()
```

Below is the error I am getting when running the multiprocessing.py

```
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example of what is working and what is not working.  Your posted description, as written, is not enough for us to help you.

Comment: @slightlynybbled I have edited the question and added both the code snippets to it.

Comment: This issue occurs when executing the program in windows, but in Linux, the program executes successfully. It would be helpful if someone can please explain why this issue is occurring in windows.